# Flex box 'Align-self' not aligning properly on carrousel

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a flexbox image carousel and I want to place the right and left buttons inside the carousel flexbox, so I positioned them as absolute. I set the wrapper to `flex-flow: row` so my gut says that whenn setting the buttons to `align-self: flex-end` and flex-start respectively the should go at the begining and the end of the flexbox **row**.

I made a quick codepen to ilustrate the matter: https://codepen.io/Xgr/pen/RLoWoj

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things is going wrong here:

1. `align-self` on flex *row* items is set for its cross axis (vertical).
2. Due to a change in the specs. there is an inconsistent behavior cross browsers for absolute positioned elements.

To horizontally left/right align flex *row* items when set on the flex item, use `margin-left: auto`/`margin-right: auto`, though since this won't work on i.e IE/Safari, a workaround for them is to use `left: 0`/`right: 0`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLBvRJ)

Comment: That's perfect! Tyvm.

Answer (score 2):

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
.btn-left {
  left: 0;
}

.btn-right {
  right: 0;
}
```